# R read.table header becoming part of file directory?

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying read multiple files in a folder. My program otherwise works and the file loads until I try to insert `header = T` into the argument. I want to remove the auto numbering of columns in the dataframe.

I've tried putting `header = T` in different spots after "dir, file_list[i], and sep," but have had no success. "TRUE" just shows up in different spots in the file path.

```
dir <- choose.dir() 
wd <- setwd(dir)
file_list <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = "*.tab")

for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
   assign(file_list[i],
   multiplex <- read.table(paste(dir,  file_list[i], sep = '/')))
 }
```

I receive this error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Z:\y\x\Container 17\z/TRUE/h/ No such file or 
  directory
```

I don't understand why "TRUE" is inserted into the file path. Like I said, the program works without messing with "header." I want to get rid of the automatic column titles "V11, V12, V13" etc.

Thanks

Comment: Show us exactly where you put `header=T`. It should go in the call to `read.table` after the filename you are pasting together. `read.table(paste(dir,  file_list[i], sep = '/'), header=T)` But if you are changing the working directory you probably shouldn't be pasting in the directory again anyway. Just use `fill.names` with `list.files`. And in the future use `file.path()` rather than pasting together file paths.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you so much! Problem solved. I really needed a fresh pair of eyes. I was putting `read.table(paste(dir, file_list[i], sep = '/', header = T))` instead of your correct suggestion `read.table(paste(dir, file_list[i], sep = '/'), header=T)` Don't know how my eyes kept missing that bracket... Thanks for the other tips as well.